# Error: Not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to coding and building apps. I already have a Firebase project initialized and is connected to my Flutter project (I am using Android Studio). Everything is working fine. However, I am now starting to need to use Cloud Functions and need to use some Firebase Tools and the Firebase emulators for my app. However, when I try to start the emulator I get the following errors.

`Error: Not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)`

From reading around, it looks like `firebase init` can resolve this problem, but I already have the project initialized, so I am not sure how to solve this error. Or is it okay to reinitialize the project?

I have firebase, npm, and node all installed on my machine.

```
project % firebase --version                                                     
10.1.5
project % npm --version
6.14.15
project % node --version
v14.18.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go through some steps and see if we can solve it:

1. First of all, have you added firebase.json to your project ?
2. Have you verified that the package name of the firebase.json file matches your project package name? - Check if it is the same packagename as **your** project
3. Have you connected/gotten the SHA-1 key and connected it to your firebase project?

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not have a firebase.json file, which doesn't make sense because firebase should be initialized. However, I do have google-services.json in the android/app subfolder. Should it be somewhere else? I am also building for iOS in a Flutter app. Package name does match my project in that folder. And yes, I have a SHA-1 key in my Android app in the firebase console.

Comment: My bad, meant google-services.jason!! It should be located as shown in the picture, on project -> app. umm do you have all the necessary dependencies as well ?

Comment: If you have all the dependencies, you could try following this as well: firebase init hosting . This might work better: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart#initialize

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Now I am getting a different error on emulator start, but the firebase.json file was created when I went through that process. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Good to hear! Feel free to add as an answer as well so people with similar problem can see this solution. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but the problem I think is Error: Not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)

1. Make sure your project has firebase.json or google-services.json.
2. if you haven't installed firebase tools

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

then

```
firebase init
```

Comment: My project does not have a firebase.json in the root but it does have a google-services.json folder in android/app. I believe I have already installed firebase-tools as when I do `firebase tools --version` it returns `10.1.5`. Is there another way to check if they are installed? And should I do `firebase init` if firebase is already added and working in the project?